# Appending an image to a heading using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a div with an h2 heading. I want to add an image **into** the heading. There is what I tried, but I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var h2 = document.getElementById('Five0 h2');

 var imgLogo = document.createElement("img");
 imgLogo.setAttribute('src', 'my-image.png');
 imgLogo.setAttribute("id", "imgLogo");

 h2.appendChild(imgLogo);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this snippet. Your problem is somewhere else in your code, not here.

Comment: Is the ID of your HTML element "Five0 h2"? IDs can't have spaces. http://jsfiddle.net/hjb2kqz9/

Comment: It isn't the id, it is the selector...hm

Comment: @MarcoBonelli it is on this code because when I take this out it runs fine.

Comment: Please include all your Javascript code and HTML structure.

Comment: @Harry Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) accepts only an element's ID.

Comment: @showdev Yeah, sorry, h2 is a heading within the div Five0. h2 does not have an ID

Comment: Got it, answered my own question. Thanks for the help

Comment: In that case you cannot use `getElementByID`. You might have better results using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector). http://jsfiddle.net/hjb2kqz9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Got it using jQuery:

```
 var h2 = document.getElementById('Five0 > h2');

 var imgLogo = document.createElement("img");
 imgLogo.setAttribute('src', 'my-image.png');
 imgLogo.setAttribute("id", "imgLogo");

jQuery( "#Five0 h2" ).append(imgLogo);
```

Comment: It's preferable (and shorter) to modify the properties instead of the attributes: `imgLogo.src='my-image.png'; imgLogo.id="imgLogo";`. And instead of `getElementById` you should use `querySelector`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciate it!